# Which letters to use as index in sequences?

Tags: soft-question, notation

Usually the latin letters $i,j,k,l,m,n$ are used as indexes in sequences or sets with $k$ elements ($A = \{ a_1,...,a_k \} $). But when we already used all these letters is there any recommendation? Are there any greek letters that are commonly used with the same purpose?

Comment: May I ask in what context you get so many sets with disjoint cardinalities? I also use $p,q$ in some situations.

Comment: In older literature $\nu$ is often used to index sequences and summations.

Comment: @AlexR, sure, multidimensional sequences. So, $n$ and $m$ are the sizes and $i$ and $j$ the general terms of two sequences, $l$ the number of dimensions and $k$ the general term to refer the dimensions :/.

Comment: @user136913 Maybe consider using uppercase letters corresponding to the indices as the size? $(a_m)_{m=1}^M$ for example.

Comment: @AlexR, I'm using the capital letters for the sequences and sets, but I'm going to try this to see how it looks, thanks!

Comment: @user136913 Using $\{a_i\}_i / (b_j)_j$ for the set / sequence saves you on those scarce letters, since you need to have a letter for the element and for the index anyways :)

Comment: The problem in this case would be the references for the sets/sequences in the text! :(

Comment: I believe I have also seen $\iota$ used.

Answer (score 6):

Commonly I use the following letters as indices:
$$\text{Discrete}: i,j,k,l,m,n,p,q,r,s\\
\text{Continuous}: \alpha, \beta, t, \epsilon$$
And these as sizes of discrete sets:
$$K,l,L,m,M,n,N,P,Q,r,R,s,S$$
That's of course opinion based, but these are my favorites and $m,n$ only when not in use as an index.
$r,s$ occur as sizes mostly in numerical context (quadrature formulas / interpolation degree) and $l$ mostly as the "level" of recursion or iteration in an algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

The letters $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are common for indices.

Comment: Haven't seen any of those as indicators for the maximum index, though...

Comment: @AlexR I have, but as maximum index is uncommon. As a mere index, on the other hand, it's common.

Comment: Nothing to argue about on that point ;)